# Spark missing data when get RDDs of a dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, rdd

I chain some functions bases on Dataframes and other on RDDs. So the execution looks like:

`DF -> DF -> RDD -> DF -> RDD -> RDD ...`

Sometimes, when I do `df.rdd` a lot of rows are missing.

Calling `df.cache.rdd` instead of `df.rdd` fix this issue but why do I need to cache my Dataframes before using them as RDDs?

I know I need to cache Dataframe before doing a `df.count` because of Spark optimization, but it is weird to do that to access RDDs.

Comment: Can you provide code that reproduce that issue, theoretically it's impossible to lose data when converting a dataframe to an rdd, maybe there's something missing in your code, can you post a poc here ?

Comment: Importunately it is not possible to give you the code as it use many libraries. The dataframe to rdd is a simple df.rdd.map(x => libFunction(x))